# How to adjust to the randomness of the neural network weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

The weights of the network are random during the initialization. Thus, if you train the network multiple times with multiple different random weights, you will get different results.

My question is:

1. What do you do during the hyperparameter tuning? Do you retrain the network multiple time for each hyperparameter configuration, and take the mean of the results as the value of this hyperparameter configuration? 
   And if this is the case, does anyone use the information provided by the standard deviation?
2. The final results reported on the test data. do we train the network multiple times to compensate for the random weights, or just once?

For example, in this paper [A Neural Representation of Sketch Drawings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03477.pdf),
they report the log-likelihood for different categories in this table
[image]
So I don't get the methodology behind getting these numbers.

I appreciate any clarification :-)

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here and more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In principle (and very generally speaking), we don't train NN's multiple times for a particular hyperparameter setting, so there is neither a mean nor a variance to worry about... That said, it always depends on the specific context of course (researchers who propose new algos may do such stuff, but practitioners seldom do)...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still don't get why we shouldn't worry about it. There is a stochasticity in the results, because there is a stochasticity in the initial weights.
Doesn't that affect reproducibility and the credibility of the results?

Comment: My bad - I said we don't worry about, but that doesn't mean we *shouldn't* worry about ;) In any case, as I said, models that are considered robust enough to go to production by *practitioners* are way past of reproducibility & credibility concerns; that said, check the elephant in the room [video](http://jtl.lassonde.yorku.ca/2018/07/the-elephant-in-the-room/) and [article @ Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/machine-learning-confronts-the-elephant-in-the-room-20180920/)...

Answer (score 0):

The paper you cited isn't about the network's weight initialization.
This is about the **weighting of two loss** functions as a the following key phrase reveals:

> Our training procedure follows the approach of the Variational
>   Autoencoder [15], where the loss function is the sum of two terms: the
>   **Reconstruction Loss**, LR, and the **Kullback-Leibler** Divergence Loss, LKL.

Anyway to answer your question, there are several other random factors in a neural model, not just the weights initialization.
To handle these randomness, its variance there are several methods as well.
Some of them is training the network multiple times as you mentioned and with different train-test set break up, different [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) methods and many others. 
You can fix the initial random state of random generator to get every hyper-parameter tuning process the same "randomness" regarding weights but you can and sometimes you should do it at the different stages of the training process i.e. you can use seed(1234) at the weight initialization, but at getting the train-test sets you can use seed(555) to get **similar distribution** of the two sets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Probably quoting this paper wasn't the best idea, it was just an example of results that is unclear in terms of: are they repeating the experiment, or not?
Statistically speaking, I agree with your answer (although on my side, I would consider the seed as another hyperparameter to optimize), but I am not sure if this is what practitioners do. Simply speaking, the computational resources needed will go through the roof, especially during the hyperparameter optimization, where for each configuration, we have to train the network multiple times....

Comment: Is there an acceptable compromise here? a middle ground that is computational acceptable and doesn't violate the statistics in the same time?

Comment: In practice first we have to examine the train and test data distribution and try to align them each other choosing a seed which fulfill this criteria. Then fix this seed and fixed the weight initialization seed too, we can tune the hyper-parameters. We get a much better generalization result using cross-validation, thus in practice is a must.

Comment: @OmarSamir To be quite clear, by tuning the hyper-parameters one doesn't use cross-validation, this is for getting (much) better generalization performance at the end. I just mentioned it because it is a key element of decreasing of variance and so increasing of model generalization. So as a summary find a good train-test distribution alignment fix it, train the hyper-parameters at fixed weight initialization and then apply the trained hyper-parameters at cross-validation. Note that different initialization distribution can provide different results as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say fix the seed so you get the same random init every time, and play with hyperparameters only. Of course if you wanna try different rand inits (e.g. one of https://keras.io/initializers/) then that would be a hyperparameter.